# Postgres serial values insertion

Tags: sql, postgresql, insert

From [the Postgres documentation on `INSERT`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-insert.html), default keyword should auto increment columns declared as serial.But when I combine it with select statement, it throws me an error

```
syntax error at or near "DEFAULT"
```

Here is the insert statement

```
insert into abc (id,date,serialnumber) (DEFAULT,select (data.date,data.serialnumber) from data)
```

Comment: Are you really still using the outdated 8.2 version?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DEFAULT` can only be as a "literal" for an INSERT statement in the `VALUES` clause. I cannot be used inside the column list of a SELECT statement even if that is used for an `INSERT`.

To apply the default value, simply leave out the column:

```
insert into abc (date,serialnumber) 
select date, serialnumber 
from data
```

For an example see here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/d291a/1

---

Also: do not put a column *list* into parantheses. `(a,b)` is something different than `a,b` in Postgres. The first is a single record with two attributes, the second are two different columns.

See this SQLFiddle demo here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/3a890/1 and note the difference between the two results.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Thats giving me "ERROR:  INSERT has more target columns than expressions" which why I tried explicitly giving default.

Comment: @learningtocode Did you really run **exactly** the statement I wrote? Sounds like you didn't remove the `id` column from the columnlist in the insert part or you didn't remove the parentheses around the column names (which makes the result have only a single column not two).

Comment: I did remove the id field but not the parantheses, I misunderstood your explanation, I should have removed the parantheses in select statement and not in the insert statement. Thanks so much!!! Still not sure what is single record with two attributes..